# NLTK: what should be downloaded to using sent_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk

I try to use `sent_tokenize()` from nltk so I've downloaded next

```
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")
nltk.download("punkt")

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# tokenize sentences
sentences = [sent for sent in sent_tokenize(data, "russian")]
```

But it returns me

```
LookupError: 
Resource punkt not found.
Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  import nltk
  nltk.download('punkt')

  Searched in:
- '/Users/nltk_data'
- '/usr/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
- '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
- '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/share/nltk_data'
- '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/nltk_data'
```

---

But I don't understand why, I've downloaded it.
I try to use `nltk.download()` but I don't have a lot of RAM, so it works too slowly.
What should I change there to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
nltk.download("popular")
```

it downloads the most basic tools of NLTK such as the tokenizer and the stopwords